# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este "Segmentation fault" en PHP cuando genero archivo de un tamaño considerable?

Tags: php, linux, apache

Buen día, he leído bastante acerca de este error en distintos foros en inglés

Mi servidor productivo actualmente cuenta con:

Apache: 2.4.25
PHP: 5.6.40

Mediante la librería PHPSpreadsheet en su versión 1.8.2, se generan distintos archivos de Excel, por distintos motivos (Grandes cantidades de información y estilos aplicados a la hoja de celdas) se exporta un archivo xlsx de máximo 3MB en tiempo de ejecución bastante largos (Puede llegar a los 30/40 minutos).

Y todo esto funcionaba hasta que nos mudamos y dockerizamos a nuestro nuevo servidor, cuyo SO es CentOS7 y cuenta con un docker para apache, php y otro para mysql.

Ahora, al generar estos archivos "grandes" la traza del error.log muestra el siguiente error:
`[core:notice] [pid 8] AH00052: child pid 15829 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`

Traté de replicar el error mediante máquinas virtuales en mi máquina local y en otra más, les puse SO centos7 y dockericé, incluso copié los mismos archivos de configuración del servidor productivo, sin embargo, en estas máquinas el error no aparece y me permite la descarga correctamente.

Actualmente estoy desesperado, he intentado toda solución de internet a la inversa para replicar el error antes de probar cualquier solución en el productivo, pero de ningún modo este error se replica.

Agradezco cualquier tipo de información y ayuda con una causa justificada... Sé que a estas alturas php 5.6 está bastante mandado a recoger, pero no puedo comprometer el tiempo de trabajo a una actualización si al final no va a resolver este incidente.

Comment: Usa `docker log {nombre-docker}` para ver el log del servicio, a ver si tienes más información

Comment: Al probar `docker logs` no hay ni una sola línea en la traza